# Have I successfully paramaterized/secured my query?

Tags: sql-server, security, prepared-statement, unreal-engine4

The situation:  I am building a game using Unreal Engine.  Ultimately I need my game to communicate to a database and chose to set up SQL Server in my development environment.  With the use of a 3rd party plugin I have managed to submit queries to update the database etc.  Now it occurred to me that user string input could easily result in SQL injection.  I have spent a week learning what I could comprehend on the subject and how basically sanitizing strings is a waste of time and you MUST use parameters.

My problem:

The third party solution ultimately requires I send the script as a SINGLE string to my server.  Which will require user string input appended into said string.

My solution:

1. Write a "Stored Procedure" using parameters.
2. Execute the created procedure with an appended string in Unreal Engine with user input.

First question is my code and solution parameterized effectively?

Procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <John Doe>
-- Create date: <3/5/2021>
-- Description: <Authenticate User>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE Game_Authenticate_User
(
    @AN varchar(15),
    @AP varchar(15), 
    @AI int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT @AI = AccountID FROM Accounts Where AccountName = @AN AND AccountPass = @AP
END
GO
```

Unreal Engine Generated String Where User input was "DummyUser" and "DummyPassword":

```
"DECLARE @AccountID int EXEC Game_Authenticate_User 'DummyUser','DummyPassword',@AccountID OUTPUT
SELECT @AccountID"
```

In my limited understanding this still doesn't secure myself AT ALL from SQL injection.  While my game server will be the only connection to the SQL database, I still seem to be vulnerable to the user inputting for example:  instead of `DummyPassword`, `pass',@AccountID) --INSERT DEATH AND DESTRUCTION HERE-- EXEC SomeGenericFunction('`.

My new questions:

1. Is my solution missing anything to realize the security to be gained by implementing parameterize?
2. What kind of string sensitization should I be looking to implement on the user input (If any?)

I'm still not even sure what UE4 does to protect itself from code injection internally.

Comment: No, sorry, this solution won't protect you from SQL Injection. Because you're building a single string to execute it will still be possible to inject code via your username and password fields, e.g.: `declare @AccountID int; EXEC Game_Authenticate_User '', ''; drop table Accounts; --DummyUser', 'DummyPassword'...` If your 3rd party library only allows you to submit a single string for execution then you need to kick it to the curb and find a different solution. And tell them why you're going to stop using it.

Comment: Consider alternatives. e.g.: the MonoUE and USharp extensions allows you to write your own C# code, so maybe you could use `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameter` objects directly and correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the confirmation on my concerns and the recommendations.  I will start looking into another option.   I have a question in to the creator on his marketplace, asking him to provide an example of how to securely use parameterization in order to take user input.  I haven't wrote much code into UE4 directly as my C++ skills are far from dependable.

Comment: This sparks a question for me:  If I wrote in the Includes directly into the engine so I can create sqlparameter objects.  Then I create a function taking user strings and defining the parameters. Could I then take the parameters into the 3rd party solution by reference to get the security I am after?  Furthermore, does/can a parameter need to be declared as a global variable if I am going to use it this way?